# How to get the correct row XML?

Tags: php, xml, import, xml-parsing

For writing my XML I use the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('import.xml');
foreach($xml->Классификатор->Группы->Группа as $group)
echo $group->Наименование . '<br />' .
     $group->Ид . '<br />' .
     $group->Группы->Группа->Наименование . '<br />' .
     $group->Группы->Группа->Ид . '<br /><br />';
echo '<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />';
foreach($xml->Каталог->Товары->Товар as $item)
echo $item->Наименование . '<br />' . $item->Ид . '<br /><br />';
```

**all XML file is [here](http://zalil.ru/33972674)**

I need to get the name of the product (Каталог->Товары->Товар->Наименование), the name of the parent category(Классификатор->Группы->Группа->Наименование) to which it belongs  and the name of sub-categories (Классификатор->Группы->Группа->Группы->Группа->Наименование ), ie
so it turned out:

```
товар (Каталог->Товары->Товар->Наименование)
его категория (Классификатор->Группы->Группа->Наименование)
его подкатегория (Классификатор->Группы->Группа->Группы->Группа->Наименование)
```

How to do that?

Comment: @Loki - As a warning, insulting those who are trying to help you out here is not acceptable behavior. I've removed the offending comment, but please don't do this again. Stack Overflow is an English-only site, so his point is valid that the question should be understandable to anyone speaking English.

Comment: @BradLarson i write my question on 2 lamgeusges - on eanglish and russian for all user can understand question. I did not insult nobody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect a hash array containing group ids as keys and all nessesary values. Then finding group name and properties by id becomes simple. Here is working example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/tmp/1.xml');
$groups = array();
foreach($xml->Классификатор->Группы->Группа as $group) {
  $groups[ (string) $group->Ид] = array(
    "name" => (string) $group->Наименование,
  );
  foreach($group->Группы->Группа as $subgroup) {
    $groups[ (string) $subgroup->Ид] = array(
      "name" => (string) $subgroup->Наименование,
      "parent" => (string) $group->Наименование
    );
  }
}
foreach($xml->Каталог->Товары->Товар as $item) {
  $group = $groups[ (string) $item->Группы->Ид];
  echo $item->Наименование ."\n". 
       (isset($group["parent"]) ? $group["parent"]."\n" : "").
       $group["name"]."\n\n";
}
```